# Why won't my emulator launch? *my first android app*

Tags: android

I am writing my first android app.  Literally, I haven't written a line of code yet.  I am following a simple tutorial for setting up my dev environment (made by google) and every time that I try to launch my app (one that is auto-generated and does nothing) it fails.

When I try to 'run' the application directly from android studio *without* an emulator [API 17] open, I get no warning but nothing happens.

When I try to 'run' the application directly from android studio *with* an emulator [API 17] open, I get an error.  The error states "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"

To research this error, I tried to add lines to the build.gradle file that specifies the sdk version like so: 
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

this results in the gradle file not being able to be built.

I verified that my project settings have a lower minsdkversion set then my current emulators version.

I am not sure how to get this to actually run at this point.  Realistically, environment setup should not be this difficult -- unless I am missing something.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your SDK manager and downloading all the APIs within your min-max android versions.
You can try running your App for a single Api version to get started.

Comment: What I've done is downloaded the API 17 version through the SDK and android AVD managers.  No change....